# Export server-side function for client-side use

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mapbox

I have a function that attempts to use [MapBox](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-js) to autocomplete an `html` input field. I want to make a [geocoding call](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/geocoding/) on `keydown`, so that users don't have to fully type their city name.

In `app.js` I use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) so that my API key is accessible via `process.env.MAPBOX_TOKEN`, and require `Mapbox`:

**app.js:**

```
require('dotenv').config()
const mbxGeocoding = require('@mapbox/mapbox-sdk/services/geocoding');
const geocodingClient = mbxGeocoding({ accessToken: process.env.MAPBOX_TOKEN });
```

I now want to make `geocodingClient` accessible to some client-side jQuery code, so that I can call a function `geocoder` on `keydown` in a form `<input>` field. **How can I do this?**

The below throws the error `geocodingClient is not defined`. How can I make this server-side function available to client-side code?

**public/js/mapBox.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#citySearch').on('keyup', function(){
        var location = $(this).val();
        console.log("Location: " + location);

        async function geocoder(location){
            try {
                let response = await geocodingClient
                    .forwardGeocode({
                        query: location,
                        limit: 2
                    })
                    .send();
                console.log(response.body.features[0].place_name)
            } catch(err){
                console.log(err.message);
            }
        }
        geocoder(location)
    })

});
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can't expose your backend in client side. Also, you shouldn't.**

You need to communicate between ends and assume they are unrelated.

Send a request to the server and deal with the returning response.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#citySearch').on('keyup', function(){
    var location = $(this).val();
    console.log("Location: " + location)
    //1.  request to back end with data and deal with response with
    // http libs (ajax, node http/https, axios, etc...)
  })
});



// 2. Reach a route to invoke the async function and respond the result



// 3. this should be at the backend and responding an answer to route that respondes to front.
 async function geocoder(location){
  try {
      let response = await geocodingClient
          .forwardGeocode({
              query: location,
              limit: 2
          })
          .send();
      console.log(response.body.features[0].place_name)
  } catch(err){
      console.log(err.message);
  }
}
// this should be at the backend and responding an answer to route that respondes to front.
```

Comment: Thanks - this is helpful. I was hoping that I wouldn't have to go down this road, as I'm trying to create an autocomplete that calls function on typing. This would require making an ajax call on `keydown`?

Comment: @fugu Yes that's generally how it goes, on every key down, ping the server for a list of autocompletes, alternatively, ping the server for the full list of data at the start and do the autocomplete locally.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is include mapbox clientside script in to your html.

for details you can see below link

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-js#pre-bundled-files-on-unpkgcom

something like below.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@mapbox/mapbox-sdk/umd/mapbox-sdk.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  var mapboxClient = mapboxSdk({ accessToken: MY_ACCESS_TOKEN });
  $('#citySearch').on('keyup', function(){
    var location = $(this).val();
    console.log("Location: " + location);
    async function geocoder(location){
        try {
            let response = await mapboxClient.geocoding
                .forwardGeocode({
                    query: location,
                    limit: 2
                })
                .send();
            console.log(response.body.features[0].place_name)
        } catch(err){
            console.log(err.message);
        }
    }
    geocoder();
  })
}); </script>
```

Comment: But then how can I access `MY_ACCESS_TOKEN` (server-side)?

Comment: you will need to pass it in client as well

Comment: @fugu for proper use of tokens see https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/how-to-use-mapbox-securely/ you can create additional tokens for your client app

Comment: I will try this tonight. Assuming both this and the answer given by @FedeSc are valid approached - is there any reason that this would **not** be preferable to the other approach?

Comment: @fugu this is for applications that aren't using JS moduling system (i.e nodejs beckend). as written `If you aren't using a JS module system, you can use a <script> tag referencing pre-bundled files on the CDN unpkg.com.`
basically you will import your functionality twice (back and front) and you will have to deal with secret tokens in client side just to avoid an http request.